# I wasn’t able to joke with my position (meaning)

Tags: comprehension

Source (news article): [Russian Comedians Fess Up to Pranking Elton John by Pretending to Be Vladimir Putin](https://gma.yahoo.com/russian-comedians-fess-pranking-elton-john-pretending-vladimir-181032281--abc-news-celebrities.html#)

Example:

> “We just couldn’t pass up this opportunity to see what Elton John would say if he thought he was really speaking to Putin,” Krasnov, who played Putin, said in a telephone interview.
>   The voice of Putin in recording does not much resemble the real Putin; Krasnov said he had not tried to imitate Putin much because he knew Elton John would probably not be able to tell the difference since he was speaking Russian.
>   “I don’t have much experience in this, so **I wasn’t able to joke with my position**,” Krasnov said.

What exactly does he mean by saying he wasn't able to joke with his position?

Comment: Maybe he wanted to say that the prank had been so "high-level" that it took all of his skill just to get through to Elton John, and hence he had not been able to play some joke on Elton John during the conversation - the way he would if his collocutor were a more ordinary guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that he wasn't able to joke, **given** his position...
like,
1. He was not in a position to joke because of being in a trying or difficult situation.
2. He did not have much experience dealing with these situations so he was not in a position to joke.
or anything like that.

It was too difficult to joke, and the comedian was simply trying the pull this off.